# C++ out-proc COM server rewritten in VB.NET and shared accross C++ EXE

Tags: c++, vb.net, com

I have re-written a out-proc COM ErrorModule in VB.NET. The module is used by our old COM C++ programs. The VB.NET is using the same GUI for the COM Class and its Interface, and the same DispId as the old C++. I am trying to make this transparent for the C++ module so we don't need to change them. They simply compile using the old ErrorModule.h generated from the old  ErrorModule.idl, which I intend to keep. It works but:

The old:

```
(C++ COM client)  MainProgram.exe
(C++ COM server)  LogicalModule.exe
(C++ COM server)  ErrorModule.exe, implements IError
```

Is now:

```
(C++ COM client)  MainProgram.exe
(C++ COM server)  LogicalModule.exe
(VB.NET COM assembly)  ErrorModule.dll, re-implements IError

MainProgram.exe
    ErrorModule.dll

LogicalModule.exe
    ErrorModule.dll
```

Typically MainProgram calls LogicalModule. If LogicalModule detects an error, a COM class ErrorModule will be created and its interface IError returned to MainProgram, where IError.showErrorDlg() will be eventually called.

Can this work in VB.NET ? Can an IError COM interface from the ErrorModule of LogicalModule be used by MainProgram?

I am testing the marshalling of IError between the two C++. It works but I have the following problem. Everytime I make a change to ErrorModule.dll in VB.NET, rebuild, then the marshalling stops working and I get and error "The value of ESP was not properly saved...".

I realized if I rebuild the C++ modules, then it stars working again? I put one line of code in comments in ErrorModule.dll, rebuild, then it stop working with the ESP error ? There is no direct link between the two ? All rebuilding the VB.NET does is updates the registry, as far as I know ?

Comment: Pretty vague.  You get that error in a C++ program when you add or remove method arguments.  That's completely illegal, you cannot change IError.

Comment: I do not change IError. One module creates an instance of it: pitfError. Returns it as a byref argument: **pitfError of another module. Other module tries using it, then ESP exception.

Answer (score 0):

A thought over what I am trying to do an now I think its pretty insane. A COM interface created by an .NET interface, returned to a C++ EXE which in turn passed it to another C++ EXE which tries to call its method. With variables on the stack of a calling process, used by another process ? I am no stack expert but I am starting to think this is totally insane.

The solution was provided by Steven Doggart in an earlier post. I will keep the out-proc server in C++ the way it is, but it will be an empty shell, a proxy to a VB.NET COM impleting the same functionnalities but in VB.NET instead of C++.

Sorry for the lengthly messages.